# Customizing Azure DevOps REST API call

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the REST APIs of Azure DevOps to work with a release pipeline.
The release pipeline uses task as part of an agent job.
This task deploys a VM into Azure using an ARM Template file and a parameters file.
So far I can execute the release pipeline successfully with the Azure DevOps REST APIs and it deploys the VM successfully with the code below.

[snippet of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1RB5.png)

Using the GUI I can also successfully customize the release pipeline when executed.  For example I can add values to the “override template parameters” field below in the screenshot.

However after searching I see nothing from Microsoft on how to access fields within tasks when executing a release pipeline in their Azure DevOps REST API documentation.

How can I modify my “response body” in the code below to access one of the fields in a pipeline task such as “override template parameters” when I call this pipeline?

```
const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, reqBody) => 
{
  const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>
  {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, true);                                                    // Send a request
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');                     // Build the request header
    request.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('Basic' + ":" + pat)); // Supply authentication

    request.onload = () =>
    {                                                                                 // Retrieve the response
                                                                                      // Check the status of the request...
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400)
      {
        myOutput.innerHTML = "Request Status: Valid | "; 
        resolve(request.response);
      }
      else
      {
        myOutput.innerHTML = "Request Status: Invalid |";
        reject(request.response);
      }
    } // onload

    request.send(JSON.stringify(reqBody));
  }); // promise

  return promise;
};
```

```
/*
  Execute a pipeline
*/
function run_pipeline()
{
  var reqLink = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ org_name+'/'+ prj_name+'/_apis/pipelines/'+pipeline_id+'/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1';

  // CHANGE RESPONSE BODY TO THE DESIRED PIPELINE NEEDED TO BE RUN
  responseBody = {
    "previewRun": "false",
    "resources": null,
    "stagesToSkip": null,
    "templateParameters": null,
    "variables": null,
    "yamlOverride": null
  };

  sendHttpRequest('POST', reqLink, responseBody).then(responseData =>
    {
      // parse the obtained data
      var data = JSON.parse(responseData);
      myOutput.innerHTML += " Pipeline Executed!";
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => 
    {
      var message = JSON.parse(error);
      myOutput.innerHTML += " Error with Data...";
      console.log(message);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below rest api. how did it go? – Levi Lu-MSFT

Comment: Hi, yes it worked. However, I am looking for a way to update the storageName parameter from fabrikam to "foo".

Comment: Hi @Malik you can use create release rest api to update the storageName parameter. Please check out below update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the the fields in a release pipeline task. You might need to use [get release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=6.0-preview.6`

You can get the release id and environment id from the Release ui address bar. see below:

[image]

Then you will find the fields of the task in response (**deployPhasesSnapshot** -->**workflowTasks**-->**inputs**)

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to update the storageName parameter. Please follow below steps:

1, create a pipline variable named `storageName`. And check `Settable at release time`. See below screenshot:

[image]

2, Set the `override template parameters` field of the deployment task as below:

[image]

3, If you want to create a new release. You can call [create release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

`POST https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1`

Then update the pipeline variable `storageName` in the request body. See below:

**Request Body**:

```
{
    "definitionId": 7,

    "variables": {  
                    "storageName": {
                                      "value": "foo" 
                                   }
                 }
}
```

Then the `storageName` parameter will be overrode to "foo".

**Update 2:**

If you want to update a existing release. You need to call [update release environment rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
 PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=5.1-preview.6.
```

First you need to set the pipeline variable `storageName` scope to its stage. See below:

[image]

Then update the `storageName` value in the request body. And set `status` to `inProgress` to redeploy the stage. So that the overrode storageName will be reflected in the release.

```
{
    "status": "inProgress",


    "variables": {  
                    "storageName": {
                                      "value": "storageName-rest-api-three" 
                                   }
                 }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for being unclear, I do want to update an existing release pipeline's variable. Would the request body you have above work?

Comment: Hi @Malik. Please check out above update 2. I tested above request body and it was working.

Comment: Hi @Levi how would I create a new release with a pipeline variable at a specific stage?